# Abstract class with method to abstract ambiguous prototype doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, overriding

Lets say I have 2 classes Player and Npc and a abstract class Entity.

How do I make Entity class ignore ambiguous classes in prototype it shouldn't care its abstract.
Only option I see is to resort to a Wrapper for both which seems like a very stupid thing to do.

Npc class

```
class Npc : Entity {
    private NpcSkills skills; //npc skills
    ...

    public Npc(int id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        skills = new NpcSkills(this); //<- Yes its a new class NpcSkills not Skills.
        ...
    }

    public override NpcSkills getSkills() //<-- Method has same name, different class then Player.
    {
        return skills;
    }
    ...
}
```

Player class

```
class Player : Entity
{
    private Skills skills;
    ...

    public Player(int id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        skills = new Skills(this); //<- Yes its a new class NpcSkills not Skills.
        ...
    }

    public override Skills getSkills() //<-- Method has same name, different class then Npc.
    {
        return skills;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Entity class

```
abstract class Entity
{
    private int id;

        public abstract void getSkills(); //<-- fail how would I match this against 2 classes
        //public abstract Skills getSkills(); //<-- fail for npc
        //public abstract NpcSkills getSkills(); //<-- fail for player
        //public abstract SkillsWrapper getSkills(); //<-- won't take this path haha.

        public void updateDamageTaken(double damageTaken)
        {
            int currentHp = getSkills().getHealth(); //<-- want it like this.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive `Skills` and `NpcSkills` classes from the same base class, say `SkillsBase`, and declare your `getSkills` method as follows:

```
public abstract SkillsBase getSkills();
```

Comment: Ya..... that's what i'm trying to avoid making Wrappers.. I was thinking maybe there is like a object thing I could use or something like T<> i dont know.

Comment: @SSpoke, as far as I can see this the only approach for you to implement exactly what you want (`int currentHp = getSkills().getHealth(); //<-- want it like this.`). With generics you won't know the type of generic parameter for skills class - `getSkills<?is it player or npc skills?>().getHealth()`, with return type of `object` you won't know to which type to cast it - `((?Skills or NpcSkills?)getSkills()).getHealth()`. But the peculiar thing is that if you implement base class for both `Skills` and `NpcSkills`, you could use these two approaches as well (with a bit of additional plumbing).

Comment: Ya I would.. I would like it to be  `if(object is NpcSkills)` .. `else if(object is Skills)` just to avoid the wrapper.. but I also don't want to change `getSkills()` into `object getSkills()` those getSkills() are used everywhere and can't make them be returning object's now. Is it possible to make it a `object` just for abstract class?

Comment: No, it's not possible to limit it to only abstract class.